# Self answering a Intercom and playing louldy for person to response

Tags: arduino-mega

We have two labs - one in 1st floor and other at 2nd floor. We are connected by intercom - both the labs has one device each. The issue is that the person who sits near the intercom is busy through out day answering the intercom and reaching out to the person for whom the call is made for.

This is very tiresome and hence I wish to automate this. I have an Arduino Mega 2560 board. My plan is to make Arduino receive the call ask for the person whom the caller is reaching out and play the name loudly over speaker in all rooms of labs (to attended the phone). If the user does not turns up even after 3 repeated times of calling - disconnect the call. If the user answers the phone by picking up the receiver then turn the conversation speaker mode off until call has not ended.

I have Arduino Mega 2560 board which has 4 serial ports but I am not user what would be the circuit to make this functionality workable? What are the extra h/w required and concept of its implementation.

Comment: There are several components here, each can be pretty complex by itself; do you want to programatically voice-recognize the person's name? do you know what interface the intercom is using? POTS? do you want the Arduino to play a wave files with every name pre-recorded or do you want voice synthesis? will the person/user answer from his desk or should he reach the intercom itself?

Comment: No I do not want to recognize any user voice - it just that when intercom rings the playback should state - "Whom do you want to speak to?". The user would reply with a person name. This name has to be played on an Audio system for the person to attend the call

Comment: and the intercom is plain old telephony system or some kind of digital system? if digital, which kind?

Comment: Well its plain old telephony type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to break it down to several components:

- **Interfacing with POTS** (Plain Old Telephony System):
  There is [a nice article](http://ww.joes.com/intercom/index.html) by Joe Doll describing how to interface an Arduino and POTS. POTS involves high voltage during both idle and ringing time (48 V DC, superimposed 90 V AC) and the circuit itself is [mostly analog](http://www.joes.com/intercom/circuit.html). You can find the required parts and their values in his article, which goes down into the nasty details in a spectacular fashion. Here is the analog circuit, involving the Arduino, from his post:

[image: Arduino interfacing POTS from Joe Doll's website]

Consider that there are other projects performing similar task in a different manner, like [this one](http://brohogan.blogspot.co.il/2009/12/telephone-interface.html), and [this one](http://blog.andrewstella.com/2013/12/new-project-arduino-rotary-phone.html) which specifically explains how to record sound from an old rotary phone.

- **Play/Record sound from Arduino Mega 2650:**
  There are many projects that describe how to [Play](http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-playing-wav-files/) or [Record](http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Mega-Audio-File-logging/) sound using Arduino. Most involve a SD card to store the wav files. There is also the option of an MP3 shield, that comes with a pre-built SD card slot, such as [this one](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10628). They are fully documented and are easy to interface with.
- **Code that encapsulates the Logic**:
  Here you could decide how many times the Arduino should play the recorded name, and what happens if the user won't answer. The disconnection will be done utilizing the POTS interface you created in bullet #1. In addition, you should handle the logic of what happens when the user does answer. It is not clear what you mean by 'receiver', but if you plan to have a remote extension or similar, some extra work will be required.

As a side note, it might be easier to create/re-use a walkie-talkie kind of wireless communicator, accompanied by an Arduino, to signal or broadcast the names of the people called. This might not include reuse or interfacing with the current intercom device, but by thus I believe it will make development easier and faster.

Comment: Thanks for all the information and links. Can you please let me know how to use Arduino with walkies-talkie for the same functionality?

Comment: it depends on many factors; what kind of walkie talkie and if you interface it or build it yourself. There are many projects on the web. I suggest you take one as an example, study it, and open specific questions when you're stuck